# General Browser display statistics

Tags: browser, cross-browser, resolution, screen-resolution

I need to come up with some figures on browser display (resolution) statistics. Obviously there is W3 Schools, however they state that these are results from their site and is biased towards tech savvy users. Does anyone know of some stats that are more general in nature? They need to be credible.

Comment: You can always sign up for compete.com.

Comment: you could try your luck on superuser.com as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually just google for "Browser Statistics" and use the top ones that appear.  W3Schools is fairly accurate even though they are only gathering a small percentage of the world's traffic.    W3Counter (http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) is another good one.

Answer (score 6):

unfortunately all the answers so far are giving SCREEN resolution and not the requested BROWSER display/resolution. They are two different entities. Not everyone has their browser open to 1920x1080 on their 1920x1080 monitor.
There are no actual statistics (that I can find) on BROWSER display size. This might help with explanations: https://css-tricks.com/screen-resolution-notequalto-browser-window/

Comment: In case you don't answer the question it's better to make comment.

Comment: can't make a comment until you have reputation. stack overflow wouldn't allow me to comment, so i posted an answer and there IS an answer in the link i shared. unfortunately, there really isn't a all encompassing data house that publicly publishes browser display size, but at the end of that article i linked it does give the average browser size that they found as well as ways to compute browser sizes with the screen size information. it's just not 100% accurate.

Comment: [This page](https://mozilla.github.io/meao/2018/01/24/browser-sizes/) has a chart of actual browser widths in CSS pixels, as opposed to raw screen widths.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're wanting statistics relevant to an existing site, Google Analytics includes tracking of such info for whatever site it's installed on.

You can also take a look at W3Counter's [global stats](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) page, which displays aggregate data from something like 15,000 different sites that use their tracking services.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a fairly old question, nonetheless I had the same question today and couldn't find any "good" and current numbers, so I'm giving out stats from one of the top 100 sites in Germany. The stats are based on the raw numbers from GoogleAnalytics and have been compiled from 264,069,927 page-views but be aware that the audience of that site is dominantly coming from European countries (while it does have also quite some visitors from all over the world). It's a work-related site (no gaming, no news)

I'll state the browser window resolution and the display resolution on the same site as reference.

First, **the width**:

- at least 3840px wide: 0.00% (Display: 0.05%)
- at least 3820px wide: 0.00% (Display: 0.05%)
- at least 2560px wide: 0.31% (Display: 2.04%)
- at least 2540px wide: 0.47% (Display: 2.05%)
- at least 1920px wide: 6.64% (Display: 30.17%)
- at least 1900px wide: 19.67% (Display: 30.21%)
- at least 1680px wide: 24.70% (Display: 42.35%)
- at least 1660px wide: 31.16% (Display: 42.78%)
- at least 1600px wide: 32.86% (Display: 48.50%)
- at least 1440px wide: 45.94% (Display: 59.31%)
- at least 1366px wide: 51.16% (Display: 75.09%)
- at least 1360px wide: 51.60% (Display: 75.56%)
- at least 1280px wide: 69.53% (Display: 91.64%)
- at least 1260px wide: 78.60% (Display: 91.68%)
- at least 1152px wide: 84.10% (Display: 93.08%)
- at least 1024px wide: 88.64% (Display: 95.66%)
- at least 1004px wide: 90.96% (Display: 95.72%)
- at least 800px wide: 98.03% (Display: 96.14%)
- at least 780px wide: 98.24% (Display: 96.14%)

And here is **the height**:

- at least 2160px high: 0.78% (Display: 2.33%)
- at least 1600px high: 32.86% (Display: 48.50%)
- at least 1440px high: 45.94% (Display: 59.31%)
- at least 1200px high: 82.45% (Display: 92.62%)
- at least 1080px high: 87.18% (Display: 94.01%)
- at least 1050px high: 88.05% (Display: 94.22%)
- at least 1024px high: 88.64% (Display: 95.66%)
- at least 900px high: 97.26% (Display: 95.96%)
- at least 864px high: 97.48% (Display: 95.98%)
- at least 800px high: 98.03% (Display: 96.14%)
- at least 768px high: 98.41% (Display: 98.57%)
- at least 600px high: 99.11% (Display: 98.75%)

I took the "Common display resolutions" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution as reference

Two final notes:

- I made an additional entry for each width subtracting 20px because ~20px is often the size of the scrollbar. This explains the sometimes quite big gaps between e.g. 1920px vs 1900px. I did not do the same for heights, but be aware that the "taskbar" (if any) might explain/cause some differences there as well!
- On very small displays, people seem to have windows that are larger than the screen itself, if the data collected by GoogleAnalytics and my calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Best free stats are going to be from http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-ww-monthly-200912-201012
Customizable range is accurate to 30 days. Also includes other browser stats.

Comment: BROWSER size often to usually is smaller than desktop size.  Those stats only show maximum possible viewport sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Big no. W3 stats show W3 visitors, and even they state, that it is not representative.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would go for the W3Counter. At the moment, it shows the statistics based on 75.676 sites which use the W3Counter. For example see http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2014&month=5 for May 2014.

Then, there is the StatCounter. They also collect data of web sites which use their analytics tool and they have a market share about 2% of all web sites. The statistics can be found here http://gs.statcounter.com/.

If you now merge these two statistics, you would get a really credible statistic which will nearly represent the reality (although the statistics have nearly the same values anyway).