# Are there any publicly available aggregators of client data (user-agent, screen resolution, OS)?

Tags: operating-system, statistics, user-agent, public, screen-resolution

Emphasis on **publicly available** and **aggregate**

I'm looking for data similar to stats you'd see for your own site in Google Analytics but for a large chunk of the web:

TOP 10

- Browsers
- Operating Systems
- Screen Resolutions

Perhaps even aggregate statistics for [Alexa's Top 10](http://www.alexa.com/topsites)?

---

I guess a potential benefit here would be to establish which browser/resolution/OS combinations would give the most bang for your time to test for a new site.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220263/general-browser-display-statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php